# Why is Git Rebase Refusing to squash a merge

Tags: git, rebase, squash

I am trying to squash the first 14 commits together: `git rebase -p -i HEAD~14`. The following image shows the commits that I am trying to squash. Commits `f101fff106d`, `6a1cb904b73`, `89001a588c3`, `656d21e1bfa` are the merges that I did with develop.

[image]

The problem is that after I exist rebase i get the following error:

> Refusing to squash a merge: 656d21e1bfa84b866031e904c303662878370d14

I don't understand why I am getting that error. How can I solve it?

---

```
    pick 290c32355fd Squash all commits
    s 4aa246bc4c5 Squash Commits
    s 656d21e1bfa merge with develop
    s a7448275954 tasks to do
    s 4c6198cd0f0 fix print
    pick f101fff106d Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin' into into TEST_ENGINE
    s 30f9adbe65a remove unused check
    s 7343e3565ad fix error
    s 1e3dc014f67 fix isokToupdate
    s c16412a7f83 fix isokToupdate
    pick 6a1cb904b73 Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin' into TEST_ENGINE
    pick 89001a588c3 Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin' into TEST_ENGINE
    s a32ce67d389 fix namespace
    s 2d0c8ee55e8 Refactor code and correct functional errors
    
    # Rebase a2c59ed4e21..2d0c8ee55e8 onto a2c59ed4e21 (14 commands)
    #
    # Commands:
    # p, pick = use commit
    # r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
    # e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
    # s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
    # f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
    # x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
    # d, drop = remove commit
    #
    # These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
    #
    # If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
    #
    # However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
    #
    # Note that empty commits are commented out
```

Answer (score 1):

First: try not to combine `git rebase -p` with most interactive operations, including squash, fixup, or rearrangements, as it has a bunch of bad behaviors that can result.  If you have a Git version that is 2.18 or later, use the new `--rebase-merges` option (`git rebase -r` for short) which is much better behaved.

As for the particular error you are seeing: it's technically impossible to rebase a merge at all, and neither `git rebase -p` nor the new improved `git rebase -r` do so.  What they do instead is *re-perform* the merges.  When they do re-perform the merge, that's exactly what they do: re-perform the merge by running `git merge`.

The squash and fixup operations that `git rebase` does are equivalent, more or less, to using `git commit --amend` (and in the old interactive shell script, actually *ran* `git commit --amend`).  But `git merge` does not have the equivalent of `--amend`: Git just does not know how to do that.

When using the new `-r` option, you should be able to *drop* a merge, if you want to just omit it; or, if you want to turn it into a squash-not-really-a-merge, you can replace the `merge` command with an appropriate `exec git merge --squash` command.  It would still take a second interactive `-r` rebase to squash the resulting commit into an earlier one.